# C move node in linked list

Tags: c

I wrote a program that move a node in a linked list to index according the user choice and i only can move the nodes forward but if the user want to move frame 2 (node 2) to frame 1 (node 1) I have no clue how to do that if someone know how to do that and can help I will realy appreciate that. this is the function

```
FrameNode* MovePos(FrameNode* list, int number_of_nodes)
{
    char name[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    int index = 0, pos = 1;
    bool flage = false;
    printf("Enter the name of the frame\n");
    fgets(name, STR_LEN, stdin);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
    flage = searchInList(list, name); // function that search if the name exists in the list
    if (!flage)
    {
        return list;
    }
    printf("Enter the new index in the movie you wish to place the frame\n");
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &index);
        getchar();
        if (index > number_of_nodes)
        {
            printf("please enter number between 1-%d\n", number_of_nodes);
        }
    } while (index > number_of_nodes);
    FrameNode* p = list;
    FrameNode* prev = p;
    while (strcmp(p->frame->name, name))
    {
        prev = p;
        p = p->next;
        pos++;
    }
    for (int i = pos; i < index; i++)
    {
        prev->next = p->next;
        p->next->next = p;
    }
    for (int i = pos; i > index; i--)
    {
        // here the code that do that supposed to be
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `gets(name)` - Buffer overruns - Use an alternative. e.g. `scanf` or `fgets`

Comment: How about using the `prev` that was defined but unused? `prev = p; p = p->next;`

Comment: @oee attias Your approach is bad. The function should do only one thing: to move a node. Neither question should be present in the function.

Comment: @oee attias Pay attention to that in C it is adopted that indices starts from 0.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an editor open right now to test this but this logic should work for you.

In your while loop, check if `p->next->frame->name = name`. If it does, then that's the node you're searching for. Store `p->next` in a variable, then make `p->next = p->next->next`. This will "remove" the node the user searched for.

Loop again with your indices, stop at the index the user wants, and do something similar to the above.

```
my_stored_p_from_earlier->next = p->next->next
p->next = my_stored_p_from_earlier
```